# How to take an input field, filter the input based on a set of rules and apply to another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What would be the right way to go about the following:

Input field for title

Input field for username

Username rules: 1 to 20 alphanumeric characters, including underscores ("_"), lowercase

When the user types a title like:

- Hello World
- Pizza Group
- Crazy Ones !@#!@#!#!#***

the username field is dynamically updated as the user types the title formatting the title to meet the username rules?

Do I need some keydown with a regex? Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the regex replacement with pure JS. You can use jQuery to bind to the keyPress event (or any other you wish to). Hope this helps.

```
$("#inputfld").keypress(function() {
  var fldval = $('#inputfld').val();
  $('#inputfld').val(fldval.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g,''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following removes characters that aren't allowed, and puts underscores instead of spaces.

```
$(function() {
   $("#title").keyup(function() {
      $("#username").val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]/g,"")
                                       .replace(/ /g, "_") );
   });
});
```

Note that (possibly browser dependent) if you use `keypress` the `.val()` won't include the character from the key just pressed so the two fields will be slightly out of sync. With `keyup` they'll stay in sync unless you hold the key down and let it repeat (though I guess you could trap keyup *and* keypress to deal with that).